# Compare two files based on key, print difference in value in another file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

I have 2 large files around 1.2 GB data, with key and values, I need to compare both files based on the key and store difference in the value in the third file,

file1:

```
test1 marco;polo;angus
test2 mike;zen;liza
test3 tom;harry;alan
test4 bob;june;janet
```

file 2:

```
test1 polo;angus
test2 mike
test4 bob;janet
```

I would like to compare the first two columns of file1 with file2 (search through the entire contents of file2 in first two columns) if they match print the difference of values. Then search for the second line of file 1 and so on. Also keys unique in file 1 should be printed.

Expected Output:

```
test1 marco
test2 zen;liza
test3 tom;harry;alan
test4 june
```

The files I have are huge, containing about 100,000 lines, so I would like to make the execution fast.

Comment: Is memory usage a concern?

Comment: Also, I removed the bash, ksh and sh tags. Re-add whichever **one** you're actually using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, am new to shell script, getting below error when i run the command, 
-bash: perl: command not found
-bash: perl: command not found
-bash: perl: command not found
-bash:  datamash: command not found
-bash: perl: command not found
-bash: perl: command not found
-bash: perl: command not found
comm: ' /dev/fd/62': No such file or directory

This is running in shell script, using #!/usr/bin/env bash

Also real entries would look like below:
1332239_44557576_CONTI Lased & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_no-rule 343323H;343434311H;454656556H;343343432H

Comment: Not much mystery about the error message `bash: perl: command not found`. You're trying to call a command, perl, from bash but that command isn't found in your PATH. perl isn't a standard UNIX tool so you probably have to install it however you do that on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ comm -23 <(perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$_" for split /;/, $F[1]' file1 | sort) \
           <(perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$_" for split /;/, $F[1]' file2 | sort) | \
  datamash -g1 collapse 2 | tr ',' ';'
test1   marco
test2   liza;zen
test3   alan;harry;tom
test4   june
```

This has a lot of steps, but much of it can happen in parallel:

1. Use `perl` to turn each single line into multiple ones with a single value in each the second column instead of multiple, and then sort everything. (Note this part requires a shell like `bash` or `ksh93` that understands `<(command)` redirection.)
2. The sorting is required for `comm -23`, which will print the lines only existing in its first input file (Thus things like `test1 polo` which are in both will be suppressed).
3. Uses [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to collapse the split up lines back into one based on a common first column value, with the second column values delimited by commas.
4. Uses `tr` to turn those commas into semicolons to match the original files.

If your real files are already sorted based on the first column like your examples are, this can be improved to be more efficient:

```
comm -23 <(perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$_" for sort split(/;/, $F[1])' file1) \
         <(perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$_" for sort split(/;/, $F[1])' file2) | \
 datamash -g1 collapse 2 | tr ',' ';'
```

---

Alternatively, a pure `perl` version (that loads the entire second file into memory):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Run as perl whatever.pl file1 file2
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;

my %values;
open my $file2, "<", $ARGV[1];
while (<$file2>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split;
    push @{$values{$key}}, split(/;/, $val);
}

open my $file1, "<", $ARGV[0];
while (<$file1>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split;
    if (exists $values{$key}) {
        my %set = map { $_ => 1 } split(/;/, $val);
        delete @set{@{$values{$key}}};
        say "$key\t", join(";", keys %set);         
    } else {
        say "$key\t$val"
    }
}
```